# SFMl столкновение двух кругов в 2d

Tags: c++, sfml

**Как можно сделать точное столкновение кругов так как в SFML intersects неточный подскажите как сделать?**

Comment: если расстояние между центрами кругов меньше, чем сумма их радиусов, то они пересекаются

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: Работает но как-то криво

Comment: вот код float distance = x+r - coords.x+distpather->liseteners->at(respId)->getR();
        if (distance <= r + distpather->liseteners->at(respId)->getR())
            collision = true;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
distance = sqrt((x2 - x1)*(x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1)*(y2 - y1))
collision = (distance <= r1 + r2)
```